# PHP cURL to login to a site

Tags: php, curl, ssl, authentication

I am here with a lot of hope to solve my problem. I have this website i want to login to and access a member only page. so basically php code with cURL to login and then open a member only page. Below is the code i used. But each time i try to access member only page, it asks me to login. So it does not save in the session or cookie that i already logged in.

```
..........
set_time_limit(0);
$username = 'myemail@yahoo.com';
$password = 'mypassword';
$loginUrl = 'http://radaris.com/login/a.login';
$cookie_file_path = getcwd() . '/tmp/cookie.txt';


//init curl
$ch = curl_init();

//Set the URL to work with
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);

// ENABLE HTTP POST
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);

//Set the post parameters
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); // set to 0 to eliminate header info from response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'email='.$username.'&password='.$password."&remember_me=1");

//Handle cookies for the login
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);

//Setting CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER variable to 1 will force cURL
//not to print out the results of its query.
//Instead, it will return the results as a string return value
//from curl_exec() instead of the usual true/false.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//execute the request (the login)
$store = curl_exec($ch);

echo "<font color=red>Login</font><br>".$store."<br><br>";



$postfields = array();
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://radaris.com/my/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); // set to 0 to eliminate header info from response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
//Handle cookies for the login
// Edit: prior variable $postFields should be $postfields;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$result = curl_exec($ch);


echo "<font color=red>Report</font><br>".$result."<br><br>";
..........
```

The Result i get is :

> Login HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: nginx Date: Thu, 12 Jun 2014 14:21:01
>   GMT Content-Type: application/json Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   Connection: keep-alive Keep-Alive: timeout=20 Cache-Control: no-store,
>   no-cache, must-revalidate Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0
>   Expires: Wed, 14 Jan 2009 19:00:00 GMT X-Robots-Tag: noindex
>   {"/Rdf.showError":[["Invalid email or password","login_form"],["Check
>   your email","login_email"],["Check your password","login_password"]]}
>
> Report HTTP/1.1 302 Found Server: nginx Date: Thu, 12 Jun 2014
>   14:21:03 GMT Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Transfer-Encoding:
>   chunked Connection: keep-alive Keep-Alive: timeout=20 Location:
>   /login?backurl=%2Fmy%2F HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: nginx Date: Thu, 12
>   Jun 2014 14:21:03 GMT Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked Connection: keep-alive Keep-Alive:
>   timeout=20 Vary: Accept-Encoding Vary: Accept-Encoding Set-Cookie:
>   PHPSESSID=qdg80d48dd17hl879h86v9ruo5; path=/; HttpOnly Expires: Thu,
>   19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache,
>   must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 Pragma: no-cache Login We
>   never share or disclose your information!

The above are the headers only. in the 2nd header i get the login form again to login meaning the successful login in the first bit of my code did not save the session that is why when i access member only page, it asks to login.

I am really desperate to get this done right. Thanks everyone in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're using two separate curl handles, and you never set up the cookie stuff in the second one. Each curl handle is completely independent of each other, so if you don't tell the second handle about the cookiejar/cookiefile you created in the first one, you never actually use the cookie you got from the login request.

Technically, you do NOT have to do one-request-per-handle. A single handle can do multiple requests. The only time it might be easier to start a new one is if you made a complicated custom request with many options set, and it's easier to just start fresh rather than reset those options for the next request.

So your code sequence should be:

```
init curl
set up cookiefile/cookiefar and other options
do login request
do next next request
close curl
```

If you don't want to rewrite, then at least add the cookiejar/cookiefile options to the second request.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense. but i dont know what options to use and what remove. can you get me started by giving me simple and easy code where you just login then go to second url while you stay logged in.

Comment: can you plz give me an example from my code above and get me start on the suggested code you gave me:

    init curl
    set up cookiefile/cookiefar and other options
    do login request
    do next next request
    close curl

Thanks waiting for someone to help me since i am very new to cURL.